# Extract data from GeoJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, geojson

I am trying to retrieve the featureclass inside the GeoJSON below.

I have updated the GeoJSON below.

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
             "scalerank": 8,
             "name": "Grill",
             "website": "www.rocargo.com/SanNicolas.html",
             "natlscale": 5,
             "featureclass": "Meat"
             },
    "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-11.1086263, 59.1438153]
            }
    },
    {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
            "scalerank": 8,
             "name": "Queen Vic",
             "website": "www.rocargo.com/SanNicolas.html",
             "natlscale": 5,
             "featureclass": "Fish"
             },
    "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
             "coordinates": [-11.1190539, 59.1498404]
             }
    },
    {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
            "scalerank": 8,
             "name": "Josephines",
             "website": "www.rocargo.com/SanNicolas.html",
             "natlscale": 5,
             "featureclass": "Bar"
             },
    "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
             "coordinates": [-11.1145087,59.142496]
             }
    },
    {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
             "scalerank": 8,
             "name": "Fall",
             "website": "www.rocargo.com/SanNicolas.html",
             "natlscale": 5,
             "featureclass": "Port"
             },
    "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-11.1174109, 59.1402164]
            }        
    }
    ]
}
```

The below function can pull all the information above.

```
   func pleaseWork() {

    let urlBar = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "bars", ofType: "geojson")!

    if let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: urlBar) {
        do {
            if let jsonResult: NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {

                if let responseA : NSArray = jsonResult["features"] as? NSArray {

                        print(responseA)



                }
            }
        }
        catch { print("Error while parsing: \(error)") }

    }
```

I can pull all the information however, I am struggling to get the 'featureclass' information.  What steps am I missing?

Thanks.
asdfadsfadsfdsafdsafdsfadsfdsafdsafdasf asdfasdfadsfdsa

Comment: Whats ur error ?

Comment: Instead of getting all the info I just require the featureclass info.  So Fish and Meat for the one above.
I'm really close, been staring at screen too long today

Comment: @M.Strachan what have you tried to access the featureclass? show some code.

Comment: Can u post full JSON list ?? Something is missing.

Comment: Yes @vadian . So that only I asked him to post full JSON

Comment: I have posted the GeoJSON file from my code.  Copied and Pasted.

Comment: The formatting of the JSON is pretty misleading. I reformatted it

Comment: Hey how to do for geometery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to use `Decodable` in Swift 4. It's very simple and convenient

Create the structs

```
struct Collection : Decodable {
    let type : String
    let features : [Feature]
}

struct Feature : Decodable {
    let type : String
    let properties : Properties
    // there is also geometry
}

struct Properties : Decodable {
    let scalerank : Int
    let name : String
    let website : URL
    let natlscale : Int
    let featureclass : String
}
```

Decode the data and print the values for `name` and `featureclass`

```
let urlBar = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "bars", withExtension: "geojson")!

do {
    let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: urlBar)
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Collection.self, from: jsonData)
    for feature in result.features {
        print("name", feature.properties.name, "featureclass", feature.properties.featureclass)
    }
} catch { print("Error while parsing: \(error)") }
```

Comment: its very usefull.

Comment: Wow, that is really nice and easy to follow.  Thanks for helping

Comment: Hey how to do for geometery?

Comment: @PvDev You got an answer you accepted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52706649/how-to-extract-values-from-geojson-file-and-pass-the-value-to-tableview-in-ios-s).

Comment: @vadian i yeah accepted answer but little confused with geometery 2 dimaensional array..

Comment: @vadian can you check it out for a moment . i have raised as new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52717548/how-to-append-2d-dimensional-array-in-ios-swift?noredirect=1#comment92360781_52717548

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Step by Step only, you can achieve that.

```
if let responseA : NSArray = jsonResult["features"] as? NSArray {

   for dictVal in 0..<responseA.count
   {
       let featuresDict = responseA[dictVal] as! NSDictionary
       let propertiesDict = featuresDict.value(forKey: "properties") as! NSDictionary
       let featureClassName = propertiesDict.value(forKey: "featureclass") as! String
       print(featureClassName)
   }

}
```

Try to use [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) link for Complex JSON validation. You will get clarity.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, works very well.  That link is really useful aswell :)

Comment: 1. You shouldn't NSArray and NSDictionary.  2. Forcing-unwrapping a dictionary is a terribly bad idea.

Comment: Hey how to do for geometery

Comment: let geometryDict = featuresDict.value(forKey: "geometry") as! NSDictionary