# How to append 2D dimensional array in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, xcode

Here I am using geojson file to get a 2D array for drawing lines. I could not able to append 2D dimensional, when appending it converts into a single dimensional array.

here is the output, which I have got:

```
coordArray==[[80.2226534485817, 12.871137160770251], [80.22263333201408, 
12.871145658917484], [80.22264339029789, 12.871184881131773], [80.2225998044014, 
12.871194686684378], [80.22260718047619, 12.87121625889878], [80.22256962954998,     12.87123848481471], [80.22255957126617, 
12.871204819088353], [80.22259946912527, 12.871195013536129], 
[80.22264305502176, 12.871184881131773], [80.22263266146183, 
12.871145658917484], [80.22265445441008, 12.871135526511145]]
```

Here is a structure, which I have used:

```
struct Geodata: Codable {
let type: String
let features: [Feature]
}

struct Feature: Codable {
let type: String
let properties: Properties
let geometry: Geometry
}

struct Geometry: Codable {
let type: String
let coordinates: [[Double]]
}

struct Properties: Codable {
let name: String?
}
```

Here is the variable which I have declared for tableview`. Here I have declared two called`nameArray`and`coordinatesArray`which I need to use in`tableview`.

```
 var nameArray = [String]()

var coordinatesArray = [[Double]]()
```

Here is the code for extract geojson value:

```
     func loadGeoJson() {


    guard let jsonUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "map1", withExtension: "geojson") else { return }

    guard let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: jsonUrl) else { return }

    self.drawPolyline(geoJson: jsonData)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: jsonUrl) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }


        do {
            //Decode retrived data with JSONDecoder and assing type of Article object
            let baseData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Geodata.self, from: data)


            for featu in baseData.features {
                self.nameArray.append(featu.properties.name!)
                print("nameArray==\(self.nameArray)")


            }

            for coor in baseData.features {



                self.coordinatesArray.append(contentsOf: coor.geometry.coordinates)

                print("new coor::\(coor.geometry.coordinates)")

                    print("coordArray==\(self.coordinatesArray)")
            }


        } catch let jsonError {
            print(jsonError)
    }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
   }

}.resume()


}
```

here is my geojson file:

```html
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Dot2Globe - CZSM"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            80.2226534485817,
            12.871137160770251
          ],
          [
            80.22263333201408,
            12.871145658917484
          ],
          [
            80.22264339029789,
            12.871184881131773
          ],
          [
            80.2225998044014,
            12.871194686684378
          ],
          [
            80.22260718047619,
            12.87121625889878
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Entrance - CZSM"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            80.22256962954998,
            12.87123848481471
          ],
          [
            80.22255957126617,
            12.871204819088353
          ],
          [
            80.22259946912527,
            12.871195013536129
          ],
          [
            80.22264305502176,
            12.871184881131773
          ],
          [
            80.22263266146183,
            12.871145658917484
          ],
          [
            80.22265445441008,
            12.871135526511145
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: that *is* a proper two-dimensional array, what output do you *expect* instead of this one?

Comment: Please include only _relevant_ code in your question. If it's about appending to a 2D array, just show that code, what result you expect, and what you're seeing. How you download data, or what other objects you are using are irrelevant. Read [mcve] and [edit] your question.

Comment: @luk2302  i have updated my geojson response..

Comment: @AshleyMills how to pass this array of coordinates to next controller, when taps on table view index 1.